# Weird behaviour while creating client and server using pipes in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, client-server, pipe

Here i am trying to create a simple client and a server using pipes. I fork a process to make the child act as a client and parent as the server. Below is the code:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void errorMsg(char* msg)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", msg);
//  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int servfd[2];
    int clntfd[2];
    int chldpid;    

    if(pipe(servfd) < 0)
        errorMsg("Unable to create server pipe.!!");
    if(pipe(clntfd) < 0)
        errorMsg("Unable to create client pipe.!!!");
        
    if((chldpid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        char* txt = (char*) calloc(256, sizeof(char));
        close(servfd[1]);
        close(clntfd[0]);
        printf("@Client: Enter a string: ");
        //scanf("%s", txt);  //or fgets
        printf("Entered.!!");
        int n;
        txt = "Anything that you want will not be considered no matter what you do!!";
        char txt1[256];
        write(clntfd[1], txt, 256);
        
        //if(txt1[strlen(txt1) - 1] = '\n')
        //{ printf("asdasdas");
        //txt[strlen(txt) - 1] = '\0';}

        //int i = 0;
        //for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            //printf("%c", txt1[i]);

    while((n = read(servfd[0], txt1, 256)) > 0)
                    printf("\nAt client: %d bytes read\n\tString: %s\n", n, txt1);
}
    else    
    {
        //printf("Parent:   \n\n");
        close(servfd[0]);
        close(clntfd[1]);
        char* txt = NULL;
        int n, n1;  
        n = read(clntfd[0], &txt, 256);
        printf("Server read: %d", n);
        n1 = write(servfd[1], &txt, 256);
        printf("Server write: %d", n1);
        wait(chldpid);
    }
    exit(0);            
}
```

### Question 1:

This is what is happening. When i run the program, it only prints `Anything that yo` (exactly 16 chars) and nothing else. When i tried to see the complete contents of `txt1` using the `for` loop shown in comments, i found that there is null value (God knows from where) after `yo` in `txt1`. After it there are normal contents as they should be. Any idea why this is happening?

### Edit:

The number of bytes read and written, when i try to print them at appropriate places, are all correct. It prints `256 bytes read`. However, the size of `txt1` by strlen comes out to be '16'. Also, the program hangs after printing part of the string.

### Question 2:

When i try to get a string from user using `scanf` or `fgets` also shown in comments, the program terminates as soon as i press enter. No clue about that too as of why that could be happening.

Any insight on the behaviors would be helpful. Sorry for multiple questions. Thanks for your time.! I am using ubuntu 12.04, if that could be of any help.

Comment: Don't forget to call `fflush(NULL)` at relevant places, e.g. after your `printf` and before the `read` calls.

Comment: Tried doing it but with no affect.

Comment: Just use `char txt[256];` in the child...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added various comments and corrections to your code. it now works as intended.
Your main issue was as pointed out by codeaddict that you did not allocate buffers. I was surprized that you didn't crash with a SIGSEGV.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void errorMsg(char* msg)
{
    printf("\n%s\n", msg);
//  exit(0);
}

// move this into global space and make it const (non modifiable, easyer to debug)
const char text_to_send[] = "Anything that you want will not be considered no matter what you do!!";

int main()
{
    int servfd[2];
    int clntfd[2];
    int chldpid;    

    if(pipe(servfd) < 0)
        errorMsg("Unable to create server pipe.!!");
    if(pipe(clntfd) < 0)
        errorMsg("Unable to create client pipe.!!!");

    if((chldpid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        char txt[256]; // You have to actually allocate a buffer (aka enough memory to hold your string. You have allocated a pointer to a buffer, but no actual buffer)
        close(servfd[1]);
        close(clntfd[0]);
        printf("@Client: Enter a string: ");

        scanf("%s", txt); // since you now actually have a buffer to put the input into this no longer fails

        printf("Entered.!!\n");
        int n;
        char txt1[256];
        write(clntfd[1], text_to_send, sizeof(text_to_send)); // write only as much as you actually have to say, not the whole size of your buffer

        while((n = read(servfd[0], txt1, 256)) > 0)
            printf("\nAt client: %d bytes read\n\tString: %s\n", n, txt1);

        // this is not nessesary at this point, but it is good style to clean up after yourself
        close(servfd[0]);
        close(clntfd[1]);
    }
    else    
    {
        //printf("Parent:   \n\n");
        close(servfd[0]);
        close(clntfd[1]);
        char txt[256]; // same here, you need to actually allocate a buffer.
        int n, n1;  
        n = read(clntfd[0], txt, 256); // read into txt, not &txt. you want to read into your buffer pointed to by txt, not into the part of memory that contains the pointer
        printf("Server read: %d\n", n);
        n1 = write(servfd[1], txt, n); // do not send the whole buffer, just as much as you have actually useful information in it
        printf("Server write: %d\n", n1);

        // close the loose file descriptors, else your child will read on them forever
        close(servfd[1]);
        close(clntfd[0]);

        int status;
        wait(&status); // this is called like this. if you want to use the pid you call waitpid(chldpid, &status, 0);
    }
    exit(0);            
}
```

Comment: Beautiful answer.!! Learnt my lessons. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

In the parent process you are doing:

```
char* txt = NULL;
.....  
n = read(clntfd[0], &txt, 256);
```

which is incorrect as you are reading data in the buffer pointed to by `txt` but you've not allocated the buffer!! What you are seeing is a manifestation of an undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But even after i do a `malloc`, no change in the behavior.